# R apply custom function without for loop, expected output is matrix

Tags: r, matrix, apply

How can I apply a custom function, with multiple arguments, to return an N x M dataframe without a for loop?

For example:

```
mat1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = -1)
vec1 <- 100:107

myfcn <- function(x, vals){
  ans <- (x + vals[1]) * vals[2]
  return(ans)
}

df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(mat1), ncol = length(vec1))) # pre-allocate

for (i in 1:length(vec1)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(mat1)){
    result <- myfcn(vec1[i], vals = c(mat1$a[j], mat1$b[j]))
    df[j,i] <- result
    }
  }
  
print(df)
```

This returns the desired output matrix:

[image]

How can I skip the for-loop and use some kind of apply function to get the above output matrix?

I tried `sapply(vec1, myfcn, vals = c(mat1$a, mat1$b))`, but it returns this:

[image]

And I tried `outer(vec1, c(mat1$a, mat1$b), myfcn)`, but it returns this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you do not need a double `for` loop to populate `df`, R is vectorized and you can pass the entire `vec1` to the function each time through the loop.

```r
mat1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = -1)
vec1 <- 100:107

myfcn <- function(x, vals){
  ans <- (x + vals[1]) * vals[2]
  return(ans)
}

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(mat1), ncol = length(vec1))) # pre-allocate

for (j in 1:nrow(mat1)){
  result <- myfcn(vec1, vals = c(mat1$a[j], mat1$b[j]))
  df[j,] <- result
}
df
#>     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8
#> 1 -101 -102 -103 -104 -105 -106 -107 -108
#> 2 -102 -103 -104 -105 -106 -107 -108 -109
#> 3 -103 -104 -105 -106 -107 -108 -109 -110
#> 4 -104 -105 -106 -107 -108 -109 -110 -111
#> 5 -105 -106 -107 -108 -109 -110 -111 -112
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Now with a `sapply` loop. You don't even have to pre-allocate space, the loop will do it on its own.

```r
df2 <- t(sapply(1:nrow(mat1), \(j) myfcn(vec1, vals = c(mat1$a[j], mat1$b[j]))))
df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)

identical(df, df2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note also that if you need a tabular data structure but not specifically a data.frame, then the last `as.data.frame` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this:

```
result = sapply(vec1,\(v) (v+mat1$a)*mat1$b)
```

If you want to use `myfcn`, make a slight change to it:

```
myfcn <- function(x, v1,v2) (x + v1)*v2
result = sapply(vec1,myfcn,v1=mat1$a, v2=mat1$b)
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,] -101 -102 -103 -104 -105 -106 -107 -108
[2,] -102 -103 -104 -105 -106 -107 -108 -109
[3,] -103 -104 -105 -106 -107 -108 -109 -110
[4,] -104 -105 -106 -107 -108 -109 -110 -111
[5,] -105 -106 -107 -108 -109 -110 -111 -112
```

If you want to convert to a frame with the same names above, add the following:

```
setNames(as.data.frame(result), paste0("X",1:ncol(result)))
```

Output:

```
    X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8
1 -101 -102 -103 -104 -105 -106 -107 -108
2 -102 -103 -104 -105 -106 -107 -108 -109
3 -103 -104 -105 -106 -107 -108 -109 -110
4 -104 -105 -106 -107 -108 -109 -110 -111
5 -105 -106 -107 -108 -109 -110 -111 -112
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right lines with `outer()`:

```r
outer(mat1$a, vec1, `+`) * mat1$b
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,] -101 -102 -103 -104 -105 -106 -107 -108
# [2,] -102 -103 -104 -105 -106 -107 -108 -109
# [3,] -103 -104 -105 -106 -107 -108 -109 -110
# [4,] -104 -105 -106 -107 -108 -109 -110 -111
# [5,] -105 -106 -107 -108 -109 -110 -111 -112
```

This will also work if `mat1$b` is `-1:-5`, for example - not just in cases where it's a constant.

Comment: the actual function is much more complicated; OP is just an MRE. How can `myfcn` be used with `outer`?

Comment: The way you generalise it - or whether `outer()` is appropriate - depends what the actual function is. In this case you can do `myfcn  <- \(df, vec) outer(df$a, vec, `+`) * df$b`  and then call `myfcn(mat1, vec1)`. In general you probably don't want to do the multiplication by a vector (e.g. `* df$b`) inside the `outer()` call as the concept doesn't work so nicely with element wise operations. How or whether you can move it outside depends on your real function.

Answer (score 1):

`pmap` is the most elegant solution in my opinion.

In this particular case, there is an extra step to create the input data with vectors of the same length, but then the apply statement is as simple as `df$result <- pmap_dbl(df, foo)`

```r
library(tidyverse)

foo <- function(x, a, b){
  ans <- (x + a) * b
  return(ans)
}

# input data
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = -1) %>% expand_grid(x = 100:107)

# pmap will used named arguments if the first argument has names
df$result  <- pmap_dbl(df, foo) 

# if argument has no names, will use them as ordered
df$result2 <- pmap_dbl(with(df, list(x, a, b)), foo) 

print(df, n = Inf)
#> # A tibble: 40 × 5
#>        a     b     x result result2
#>    <int> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1     1    -1   100   -101    -101
#>  2     1    -1   101   -102    -102
#>  3     1    -1   102   -103    -103
#>  4     1    -1   103   -104    -104
#>  5     1    -1   104   -105    -105
#>  6     1    -1   105   -106    -106
#>  7     1    -1   106   -107    -107
#>  8     1    -1   107   -108    -108
#>  9     2    -1   100   -102    -102
#> 10     2    -1   101   -103    -103
#> 11     2    -1   102   -104    -104
#> 12     2    -1   103   -105    -105
#> 13     2    -1   104   -106    -106
#> 14     2    -1   105   -107    -107
#> 15     2    -1   106   -108    -108
#> 16     2    -1   107   -109    -109
#> 17     3    -1   100   -103    -103
#> 18     3    -1   101   -104    -104
#> 19     3    -1   102   -105    -105
#> 20     3    -1   103   -106    -106
#> 21     3    -1   104   -107    -107
#> 22     3    -1   105   -108    -108
#> 23     3    -1   106   -109    -109
#> 24     3    -1   107   -110    -110
#> 25     4    -1   100   -104    -104
#> 26     4    -1   101   -105    -105
#> 27     4    -1   102   -106    -106
#> 28     4    -1   103   -107    -107
#> 29     4    -1   104   -108    -108
#> 30     4    -1   105   -109    -109
#> 31     4    -1   106   -110    -110
#> 32     4    -1   107   -111    -111
#> 33     5    -1   100   -105    -105
#> 34     5    -1   101   -106    -106
#> 35     5    -1   102   -107    -107
#> 36     5    -1   103   -108    -108
#> 37     5    -1   104   -109    -109
#> 38     5    -1   105   -110    -110
#> 39     5    -1   106   -111    -111
#> 40     5    -1   107   -112    -112
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>